How can I withdraw a paper from any conference?
Recently my paper got accepted in a conference. But the registration fee was too high for me. Plus they didn’t give any review of my paper. My supervisor told me not not register it. I decided to do so. What will happen if I do not register and ask the conference committee to withdraw it?  Will I be able to submit the same paper in different conference?

You can always withdraw an accepted paper by emailing the organizers. In fact it is polite to do so as soon as you become aware that you will not attend, as your slot can then be assigned to someone else.
Just not registering creates extra work for the organizers as they will then have to follow up after the deadline and it becomes more difficult to fill a slot the closer to the conference it gets.
People withdrawing accepted contributions happens at every conference, so no one will think any worse of you and once it's withdrawn (but please wait for confirmation), you can submit it elsewhere.

You could not register or pay the fee and your paper/presentation will be removed from the program. Alternatively, you could also write to the organisers requesting to withdraw it.
You should be able to submit the same paper at a different conference.
